# GeoTools includes repeated prefix in GML output

Tags: wfs, java, geotools, gml

When attempting to write out GML encoded features that were originally collected using the Geotools WFS plugin (gt-wfs-ng), it looks like the GML output is incorrectly duplicating the feature's prefix and producing incorrect xml. For example, a simplified version of what I'm trying to do looks like this:

```
    Map<String, String> wfsParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    wfsParams.put(
            "WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL",
            "https://mrdata.usgs.gov/wfs/asbestos?service=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities");

    wfsParams.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:WFS_STRATEGY", "mapserver");

    DataStore store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(wfsParams);

    SimpleFeatureType schema = store.getSchema("ms:asbestos");

    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = store.getFeatureSource("ms:asbestos");

    Query query = new Query(schema.getTypeName());
    query.setMaxFeatures(2);

    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features = source.getFeatures(query);

    GML encode = new GML(Version.WFS1_1);

    Name schemaName = schema.getName();

    String prefix = schemaName.getLocalPart().split(":")[0];
    String uri = schemaName.getNamespaceURI();

    encode.setNamespace(prefix, uri);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    SimpleFeatureCollection simpleCollection = DataUtilities.simple(features);
    encode.encode(baos, simpleCollection);

    System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

The output I get from that snippit looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
      <gml:lowerCorner>-73.0 -179.0</gml:lowerCorner>
      <gml:upperCorner>81.0 180.0</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:featureMembers>
    <ms:ms:asbestos gml:id="asbestos.850">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
          <gml:lowerCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <ms:geometry>
        <gml:Point srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="3">
          <gml:pos>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </ms:geometry>
      <ms:rec_id>1046</ms:rec_id>
      <ms:site_name>Amargosa mine</ms:site_name>
      <ms:devel/>
      <ms:fips_code>f06071</ms:fips_code>
      <ms:huc_code>h18090203</ms:huc_code>
      <ms:quad_code>q36118NEG2</ms:quad_code>
      <ms:url>https://mrdata.usgs.gov/asbestos/show-asbestos.php?rec_id=1046</ms:url>
      <ms:oremin/>
      <ms:assocmin/>
    </ms:ms:asbestos>
    <ms:ms:asbestos gml:id="asbestos.851">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="2">
          <gml:lowerCorner>35.782971 -116.00875</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>35.782971 -116.00875</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <ms:geometry>
        <gml:Point srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="3">
          <gml:pos>35.782971 -116.00875</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </ms:geometry>
      <ms:rec_id>1047</ms:rec_id>
      <ms:site_name>Rogers mine</ms:site_name>
      <ms:devel/>
      <ms:fips_code>f06071</ms:fips_code>
      <ms:huc_code>h18090202</ms:huc_code>
      <ms:quad_code>q36118NEH2</ms:quad_code>
      <ms:url>https://mrdata.usgs.gov/asbestos/show-asbestos.php?rec_id=1047</ms:url>
      <ms:oremin/>
      <ms:assocmin/>
    </ms:ms:asbestos>
  </gml:featureMembers>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Notice that in the xml output, features members are named "ms:ms:asbestos" instead of just "ms:asbestos". I've tried modifying the values passed to the encode.setNamespace(), but while I can change the value of the first prefix I cannot turn it off. Setting values of "" or null just results in a prefix named null (i.e. "null:ms:asbestos").

Why is geotools adding the additional prefix? How do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Is ms defined correctly in the input?

Comment: @IanTurton I'm not sure, how would you recommend I go about checking that?

Comment: Grab the wfs response in a browser

Comment: Yes, if you check the WFS response without going through geotools, the prefixing is correct. See [this link](https://mrdata.usgs.gov/wfs/asbestos?request=getfeature&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&typename=asbestos&maxfeatures=2) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, but I'm not sure where it is!

The schema looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<schema
   targetNamespace="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" 
   xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" 
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.1" >

  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
          schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd" />

  <element name="asbestos" 
           type="ms:asbestosType" 
           substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" />

  <complexType name="asbestosType">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <sequence>
          <element name="geometry" type="gml:PointPropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <element name="rec_id" type="string"/>
          <element name="site_name" type="string"/>
          <element name="devel" type="string"/>
          <element name="fips_code" type="string"/>
          <element name="huc_code" type="string"/>
          <element name="quad_code" type="string"/>
          <element name="url" type="string"/>
          <element name="oremin" type="string"/>
          <element name="assocmin" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>

</schema>
```

and the FeatureCollection is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
   xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver https://mrdata.usgs.gov/wfs/asbestos?SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.1.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=ms:asbestos&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.1.1  http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:lowerCorner>30.478092 -123.713582</gml:lowerCorner>
            <gml:upperCorner>48.988906 -67.995471</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
      <ms:asbestos gml:id="asbestos.850">
        <gml:boundedBy>
            <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
                <gml:lowerCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:lowerCorner>
                <gml:upperCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:upperCorner>
            </gml:Envelope>
        </gml:boundedBy>
        <ms:geometry>
          <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:pos>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:pos>
          </gml:Point>
        </ms:geometry>
        <ms:rec_id>1046</ms:rec_id>
        <ms:site_name>Amargosa mine</ms:site_name>
        <ms:devel></ms:devel>
        <ms:fips_code>f06071</ms:fips_code>
        <ms:huc_code>h18090203</ms:huc_code>
        <ms:quad_code>q36118NEG2</ms:quad_code>
        <ms:url>https://mrdata.usgs.gov/asbestos/show-asbestos.php?rec_id=1046</ms:url>
        <ms:oremin></ms:oremin>
        <ms:assocmin></ms:assocmin>
      </ms:asbestos>
    </gml:featureMember>

    .....
```

Which look plausible to me, when GeoTools reads them it gets the following:

```
SimpleFeatureTypeImpl http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver:ms:asbestos identified extends Feature(geometry:geometry,rec_id:rec_id,site_name:site_name,devel:devel,fips_code:fips_code,huc_code:huc_code,quad_code:quad_code,url:url,oremin:oremin,assocmin:assocmin)

SimpleFeatureImpl:ms:asbestos=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: geometry<geometry id=asbestos.850>=POINT (35.783268 -116.204155), SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: rec_id<rec_id id=asbestos.850>=1046, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: site_name<site_name id=asbestos.850>=Amargosa mine, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: devel<devel id=asbestos.850>=, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: fips_code<fips_code id=asbestos.850>=f06071, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: huc_code<huc_code id=asbestos.850>=h18090203, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: quad_code<quad_code id=asbestos.850>=q36118NEG2, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: url<url id=asbestos.850>=https://mrdata.usgs.gov/asbestos/show-asbestos.php?rec_id=1046, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: oremin<oremin id=asbestos.850>=, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: assocmin<assocmin id=asbestos.850>=]
```

Which again looks good. That seems to point the finger at the encoder.

I switched to a different encoder:

```
org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration();
org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder(configuration);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
encoder.setNamespaceAware(true);
encoder.setIndenting(true);
SimpleFeatureCollection simpleCollection = DataUtilities.simple(features);
encoder.encode(simpleCollection, GML.FeatureCollection, baos);
System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

which gives:

```
<gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <gml:featureMembers>
    <null:asbestos xmlns:null="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" gml:id="asbestos.850">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
          <gml:lowerCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:lowerCorner>
          <gml:upperCorner>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:upperCorner>
        </gml:Envelope>
      </gml:boundedBy>
      <null:geometry>
        <gml:Point srsDimension="3" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
          <gml:pos>35.783268 -116.204155</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </null:geometry>
      <null:rec_id>1046</null:rec_id>
      <null:site_name>Amargosa mine</null:site_name>
      <null:devel/>
      <null:fips_code>f06071</null:fips_code>
      <null:huc_code>h18090203</null:huc_code>
      <null:quad_code>q36118NEG2</null:quad_code>
      <null:url>https://mrdata.usgs.gov/asbestos/show-asbestos.php?rec_id=1046</null:url>
      <null:oremin/>
      <null:assocmin/>
    </ms:asbestos>
```

Note how just the closing feature tag has an `ms` prefix, which is very odd.

For now could you [raise a bug](http://geoserver.org/issues/) with your test code included and a link back to this question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I agree that it seems like it's probably a bug. I'll take a look at filing a bug report, but since gt-wfs-ng is currently an "unsupported" plugin, I don't have high expectations of it being fixed any time soon.

Comment: The encoder is supported though which was why I was trying to narrow it down